# Second stage bootLoader not loading in bochs, LINUX (ubuntu 16.04), Brokenthorn osdev series

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev, bochs

I am following brokenthorn OS development series, until now I am able sucessfully run bootloader stage1 but there is some issue with loading second stage bootloader from FAT12 floppy in bochs emulator on linux machine(ubuntu 16.04) (It works fine in virtual box though). Here is my stage1 boot loader:

```
bits 16

org  0                      ;we will set segments later

start:  jmp main

;***** BPB Parameter block *****
;must start 3 bytes after start (jmp main is of 3 byte)

bpbOEM          db "My OS   "           ; OEM identifier (Cannot exceed 8 bytes!)
bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:    DB 2
bpbRootEntries:     DW 224
bpbTotalSectors:    DW 2880
bpbMedia:       DB 0xf8  ;; 0xF1
bpbSectorsPerFAT:   DW 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:     DW 18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder:    DW 2
bpbHiddenSectors:   DD 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
bsDriveNumber:          DB 0
bsUnused:       DB 0
bsExtBootSignature:     DB 0x29
bsSerialNumber:         DD 0xa0a1a2a3
bsVolumeLabel:          DB "MOS FLOPPY "
bsFileSystem:           DB "FAT12   "

Print:
    ;string pointed by ds:si, terminated by 0
    lodsb                   ;load next byte pointed by si to al
    or al, al               ;if al is zero
    jz PrintDone
    mov ah, 0eh             ;prepare fro bios vedio interuppt call
    int 10h
    jmp Print
    PrintDone:
        ret

ReadSectors :
    ;cx = no fo sectors to ReadSectors
    ;ax = strating sectors
    ;ES:BX = buffer to read to

    .MAIN :
        mov di, 0x0005       ;we will try 5 times if failed
    .SECTORLOOP :
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        call LBACHS          ;we will get absolute sector, absolute head and absolute track information from here
        mov ah, 0x02         ;prepare bios read interrupt
        mov al, 0x01         ;we will read one sector
        mov ch, byte[absoluteTrack]
        mov cl, byte[absoluteSector]
        mov dh, byte[absoluteHead]
        mov dl, byte[bsDriveNumber]
        int 0x13            ;bios read interrupt call
        jnc .SUCCESS        ;if sucessful
        xor ax, ax          ;retying again
        int 0x13            ;reset disk interuppt call
        dec di              ;decrease a try
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        jnz .SECTORLOOP
        int 0x18            ;start basic

        .SUCCESS:
            pop cx
            pop bx
            pop ax
            add bx, word[bpbBytesPerSector]         ;next read buffer location
            inc ax                                  ;next sector to read
            loop .MAIN
            ret

ClusterLBA:
;convert custer no to LBACHS
;LBA = (cluster - 2)*sectors per cluster
        sub ax, 0x0002
        xor cx, cx
        mov cl, byte[bpbSectorsPerCluster]
        mul cx
        add ax, word[datasector]                    ;base of data sectors
        ret

LBACHS:
;convert LBA to CHS
;absolute sector = (logical sector % sector per track) + 1
;absolute head = (logical sector / sectors per track) % no of heads
;absoluteTrack = logical sector / (sectors per track * no of heads)
        xor dx, dx  
        div word [bpbSectorsPerTrack]
        inc dl
        mov byte[absoluteSector], dl
        xor dx, dx
        div word[bpbHeadsPerCylinder]
        mov byte[absoluteHead], dl
        mov byte[absoluteTrack], al
        ret

main:
        cli
        mov ax, 0x07C0                                       ;0x7C0*2^4 = 0x7C00
        mov ds, ax                                          ;setup segment registers
        mov es, ax
        mov fs, ax
        mov gs, ax

        ;create stack
        mov ax, 0x0000
        mov ss, ax
        mov sp, 0xFFFF
        sti

        ;display Starting
        mov si, msgStart
        call Print

        ;load root directory table
        LOAD_ROOT:
            ;size of root directory = 32*(no of root entries)/(bytes per sector) SECTORS
            xor cx, cx
            xor dx, dx
            mov ax, 0x0020
            mul word[bpbRootEntries]
            div word[bpbBytesPerSector]
            xchg ax, cx                         ;size of root in cx

            ;location root directory = reserved sectors + (no of FATS * sectors per FAT)
            mov al, byte [bpbNumberOfFATs]
            mul word [bpbSectorsPerFAT]
            add ax, word[bpbReservedSectors]
            mov word [datasector], ax
            add word [datasector], cx            ;start of data sector

            ;read root directory into memory 0x7C0:0x0200 = 7C00+0200
            mov bx, 0x0200
            call ReadSectors

            ;find stage2 boot loader
            mov cx, word[bpbRootEntries]
            mov di, 0x0200                      ;address of root table in memory
            .LOOP:
                push cx
                mov cx, 0x000B                  ;11 character name
                mov si, ImageName               ;Image name
                push di
                rep cmpsb
                    pop di
                    je LOAD_FAT
                    pop cx
                    add di, 0x0020              ;next entry in root table
                    loop .LOOP
                    jmp FAILURE

            LOAD_FAT:
            ;save starting cluster of boot image
            mov dx, word[di+0x001A]
            mov word[cluster], dx

            ;compute size of FAT and store in cx = no of FAT * sectors per FAT
            xor ax, ax
            mov al, byte[bpbNumberOfFATs]
            mul word[bpbSectorsPerFAT]
            mov cx, ax

            ;location of FAT in ax = no of reserved Sectors
            mov ax, word[bpbReservedSectors]

            ;read FAT in memory at 0x7C0:0x0200
            mov bx, 0x0200
            call ReadSectors

            ;load image file into memory at 0050:0000 => 0x500)
            mov ax, 0x0050
            mov es, ax
            mov bx, 0x0000
            push bx

            LOAD_IMAGE:

            mov ax, word[cluster]
            pop bx
            call ClusterLBA
            xor cx, cx
            mov cl, byte[bpbSectorsPerCluster]
            call ReadSectors
            push bx

            ;compute next cluster, remember cluster entries are of 12 bits = 3/2 bytes
            mov ax, word[cluster]
            mov cx, ax
            mov dx, ax
            shr dx, 0x0001          ;devide by 2
            add cx, dx              ;equals to 3/2*cluster number
            mov bx, 0x0200          ;location of FAT in memory
            add bx, cx              ;we moved 3/2*cluster no bytes from start
            mov dx, word[bx]        ;read 2 bytes in dx
            test ax, 0x0001         ;if this was odd cluster =>  lower 12 bits, else =>higher 12 bits will be used
            jnz .ODD_CLUSTER

            .EVEN_CLUSTER:
                and dx, 0000111111111111b
                jmp .DONE

            .ODD_CLUSTER:
                shr dx, 0x0004

            .DONE:
                mov word[cluster], dx   ;new cluster location
                cmp dx, 0x0FF0          ;if this was last cluster
                jb LOAD_IMAGE

            DONE:
                mov si, msgStageTwo
                call Print
                push word 0x0050      ;segment address
                push word 0x0000      ;offset in segment
                retf                  ;far return, both of the above value will be used

            FAILURE:
                mov si, msgFailure
                call Print
                mov ah, 0x00
                int 0x16            ;wait for key press
                int 0x19            ;reboot


            absoluteSector db 0x00
            absoluteHead   db 0x00
            absoluteTrack  db 0x00

            datasector     dw 0x0000
            cluster        dw 0x0000
            ImageName      db "KRNLDR  SYS"         ;must be 11 bytes
            msgStart     db 0x0D,0x0A, "Boot Loader starting (0x7c00)....", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
            msgStageTwo  db "Jumping to stage2 (0x500)", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
            msgFailure  db 0x0D, 0x0A, "ERROR : Press Key to Reboot", 0x0A, 0x00

            times 510-($-$$) db 0
            dw 0xAA55                               ;boot signature
```

I am trying to find and load second stage bootloader at memory address 0x500. It seems second stage is not getting loaded at 0x500. Bochs just hungs just after printing "jumping to second stage"( Print call just before jumping to second stage). Here is bochs log:

```
00000000000i[     ] Bochs x86 Emulator 2.6
00000000000i[     ]   Built from SVN snapshot on September 2nd, 2012
00000000000i[     ] System configuration
00000000000i[     ]   processors: 1 (cores=1, HT threads=1)
00000000000i[     ]   A20 line support: yes
00000000000i[     ] IPS is set to 4000000
00000000000i[     ] CPU configuration
00000000000i[     ]   level: 6
00000000000i[     ]   SMP support: no
00000000000i[     ]   APIC support: xapic
00000000000i[     ]   FPU support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   MMX support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   3dnow! support: no
00000000000i[     ]   SEP support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   SSE support: sse2
00000000000i[     ]   XSAVE support: no 
00000000000i[     ]   AES support: no
00000000000i[     ]   MOVBE support: no
00000000000i[     ]   ADX support: no
00000000000i[     ]   x86-64 support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   1G paging support: no
00000000000i[     ]   MWAIT support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   AVX support: no
00000000000i[     ]   VMX support: 1
00000000000i[     ] Optimization configuration
00000000000i[     ]   RepeatSpeedups support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   Fast function calls: yes
00000000000i[     ]   Handlers Chaining speedups: no
00000000000i[     ] Devices configuration
00000000000i[     ]   NE2000 support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   PCI support: yes, enabled=yes
00000000000i[     ]   SB16 support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   USB support: yes
00000000000i[     ]   VGA extension support: vbe cirrus
00000000000i[MEM0 ] allocated memory at 0x7f8a9189c010. after alignment, vector=0x7f8a9189d000
00000000000i[MEM0 ] 32.00MB
00000000000i[MEM0 ] mem block size = 0x00100000, blocks=32
00000000000i[MEM0 ] rom at 0xfffe0000/131072 ('/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest')
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb0540
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_hdimage.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb0ed0
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_pci.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb1a50
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_pci2isa.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb2460
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_acpi.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb2e60
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_cmos.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb37a0
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_dma.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb4230
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_pic.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb4ad0
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_pit.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb5500
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_floppy.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb60f0
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_vga.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb6880
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_ioapic.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb72c0
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_keyboard.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fb7b60
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_harddrv.so
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x3fc9c50
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_pci_ide.so
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PCI  ] 440FX Host bridge present at device 0, function 0
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PCI  ] PIIX3 PCI-to-ISA bridge present at device 1, function 0
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[CMOS ] Using local time for initial clock
00000000000i[CMOS ] Setting initial clock to: Fri Jan  5 20:53:22 2018 (time0=1515165802)
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DMA  ] channel 4 used by cascade
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DMA  ] channel 2 used by Floppy Drive
00000000000e[FDD  ] cannot determine media geometry, trying to use defaults
00000000000i[FDD  ] fd0: '/dev/loop0' ro=0, h=2,t=80,spt=18
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[MEM0 ] Register memory access handlers: 0x00000000000a0000 - 0x00000000000bffff
00000000000i[VGA  ] interval=200000
00000000000i[MEM0 ] Register memory access handlers: 0x00000000e0000000 - 0x00000000e0ffffff
00000000000i[BXVGA] VBE Bochs Display Extension Enabled
00000000000i[XGUI ] test_alloc_colors: 16 colors available out of 16 colors tried
00000000000i[XGUI ] font 8 wide x 16 high, display depth = 24
00000000000i[MEM0 ] rom at 0xc0000/41472 ('/usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest')
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PCI  ] ACPI Controller present at device 1, function 3
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[IOAP ] initializing I/O APIC
00000000000i[MEM0 ] Register memory access handlers: 0x00000000fec00000 - 0x00000000fec00fff
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[KBD  ] will paste characters every 1000 keyboard ticks
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[HD   ] Using boot sequence floppy, none, none
00000000000i[HD   ] Floppy boot signature check is enabled
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PCI  ] PIIX3 PCI IDE controller present at device 1, function 1
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PAR  ] parallel port 1 at 0x0378 irq 7
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[SER  ] com1 at 0x03f8 irq 4
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] init_dev of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] register state of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[SYS  ] bx_pc_system_c::Reset(HARDWARE) called
00000000000i[CPU0 ] cpu hardware reset
00000000000i[APIC0] allocate APIC id=0 (MMIO enabled) to 0x00000000fee00000
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x00000000]: 00000002 756e6547 6c65746e 49656e69
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x00000001]: 00000633 00010800 00002028 1fcbfbff
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x00000002]: 00410601 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000000]: 80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000001]: 00000000 00000000 00000101 2a100000
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000002]: 20202020 20202020 20202020 6e492020
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000003]: 286c6574 50202952 69746e65 52286d75
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000004]: 20342029 20555043 20202020 00202020
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000005]: 01ff01ff 01ff01ff 40020140 40020140
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000006]: 00000000 42004200 02008140 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000007]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0 ] CPUID[0x80000008]: 00003028 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[SPEAK] Using /dev/console for output
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLGIN] reset of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[XGUI ] Mouse capture off
00000000000i[XGUI ] Mouse capture off
00000000000i[MEM0 ] allocate_block: block=0x0 used 0x1 of 0x20
00000004661i[BIOS ] $Revision: 11318 $ $Date: 2012-08-06 19:59:54 +0200 (Mo, 06. Aug 2012) $
00000319051i[KBD  ] reset-disable command received
00000321813i[BIOS ] Starting rombios32
00000322255i[BIOS ] Shutdown flag 0
00000322852i[BIOS ] ram_size=0x02000000
00000323280i[BIOS ] ram_end=32MB
00000363809i[BIOS ] Found 1 cpu(s)
00000377990i[BIOS ] bios_table_addr: 0x000fa438 end=0x000fcc00
00000705785i[PCI  ] 440FX PMC write to PAM register 59 (TLB Flush)
00001033717i[P2I  ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQA# set to 0x0b
00001033741i[P2I  ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQB# set to 0x09
00001033765i[P2I  ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQC# set to 0x0b
00001033789i[P2I  ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQD# set to 0x09
00001033799i[P2I  ] write: ELCR2 = 0x0a
00001034578i[BIOS ] PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0a
00001042258i[BIOS ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x00: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x1237 class=0x0600
00001044537i[BIOS ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x08: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7000 class=0x0601
00001046655i[BIOS ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x09: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7010 class=0x0101
00001046884i[PIDE ] new BM-DMA address: 0xc000
00001047504i[BIOS ] region 4: 0x0000c000
00001049538i[BIOS ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x0b: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7113 class=0x0680
00001049768i[ACPI ] new irq line = 11
00001049782i[ACPI ] new irq line = 9
00001049809i[ACPI ] new PM base address: 0xb000
00001049823i[ACPI ] new SM base address: 0xb100
00001049851i[PCI  ] setting SMRAM control register to 0x4a
00001213945i[CPU0 ] Enter to System Management Mode
00001213945i[CPU0 ] enter_system_management_mode: temporary disable VMX while in SMM mode
00001213955i[CPU0 ] RSM: Resuming from System Management Mode
00001377976i[PCI  ] setting SMRAM control register to 0x0a
00001392878i[BIOS ] MP table addr=0x000fa510 MPC table addr=0x000fa440 size=0xc8
00001394693i[BIOS ] SMBIOS table addr=0x000fa520
00001394744i[MEM0 ] allocate_block: block=0x1f used 0x2 of 0x20
00001397672i[BIOS ] Firmware waking vector 0x1ff00cc
00001402531i[BIOS ] ACPI tables: RSDP addr=0x000fa640 ACPI DATA addr=0x01ff0000 size=0x1f22
00001402568i[PCI  ] 440FX PMC write to PAM register 59 (TLB Flush)
00001403299i[BIOS ] bios_table_cur_addr: 0x000fa664
00001530917i[VBIOS] VGABios $Id: vgabios.c,v 1.75 2011/10/15 14:07:21 vruppert Exp $
00001530988i[BXVGA] VBE known Display Interface b0c0
00001531020i[BXVGA] VBE known Display Interface b0c5
00001533945i[VBIOS] VBE Bios $Id: vbe.c,v 1.64 2011/07/19 18:25:05 vruppert Exp $
00001600003i[XGUI ] charmap update. Font Height is 16
00014040953i[BIOS ] Booting from 0000:7c00
00065146879i[     ] dbg: Quit
00065146879i[CPU0 ] CPU is in real mode (active)
00065146879i[CPU0 ] CS.mode = 16 bit
00065146879i[CPU0 ] 00065146879i[XGUI ] Mouse capture off
00065146879i[CTRL ] quit_sim called with exit code 0
```

here is bochs configuration file:

```
romimage: file="/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest"
vgaromimage: file ="/usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest"
floppya: 1_44=/dev/loop0, status=inserted
display_library: x, options="gui_debug"
log: bochsout.txt
```

And this is how I am creatng and mounting FAT12 floppy

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=myfloppy.img bs=512 count=2880
losetup /dev/loop0 myfloppy.img 
mkdosfs -F 12 /dev/loop0
mount /dev/loop0 myfloppy -t msdos -o "fat=12"
dd if=LOADER.SYS of=/dev/loop0 
cp KRNLDR.SYS myfloppy
```

Also my bootloader works fine in virtual-box, below is an image
[image: boot loader stage 2]

last line "Preparing to load operating system" is part of second stage boot loader. But it fails to work in bochs, what could be the possible cause?
And finally here is second stage bootloader(if required):

```
;*********************************************
;   Stage2.asm
;       - Second Stage Bootloader
;
;   Operating Systems Development Series
;*********************************************

org 0x0                 ; offset to 0, we will set segments later

bits 16                 ; we are still in real mode

; we are loaded at linear address 0x10000

jmp main                ; jump to main

;*************************************************;
;   Prints a string
;   DS=>SI: 0 terminated string
;************************************************;

Print:
    lodsb                   ; load next byte from string from SI to AL
    or          al, al      ; Does AL=0?
    jz          PrintDone   ; Yep, null terminator found-bail out
    mov         ah, 0eh ; Nope-Print the character
    int         10h
    jmp         Print       ; Repeat until null terminator found
PrintDone:
    ret                 ; we are done, so return

;*************************************************;
;   Second Stage Loader Entry Point
;************************************************;

main:
    cli                 ; clear interrupts
    push            cs      ; Insure DS=CS
    pop         ds

    mov         si, Msg
    call            Print

    cli                 ; clear interrupts to prevent triple faults
    hlt                 ; hault the syst

;*************************************************;
;   Data Section
;************************************************;

Msg db  "Preparing to load operating system...",13,10,0
```

Comment: Is `cp boot2.bin myfloppy` correct? Or do you mean `cp boot2.bin KRNLDR.SYS` since that is the file your first stage seems to be loading?

Comment: oh I am sorry, its `sudo cp KRNLDR.SYS myfloppy` where myfloppy is the folder where I am mounting my floppy and KRNLDR.SYS is second stage boot loader. Edited @MichaelPetch

Comment: It may be because you are are attempting to use /dev/loop0 in bochs while it is still open and active as a mount point. It may be possible that after the copy of KRNLDR.SYS to the floppy the file and or fat tables haven't been flushed from memory to the device. I really recommend after you copy that you `umount myfloppy` and then do `losetup -d /dev/loop0` Then in your bochs config replace `/dev/loop0` with `myfloppy.img` . By unmounting cleanly everything will be written as expected. Bochs should then open the disk image `myfloppy.img` cleanly.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!!! `unmount myfloppy` `losetup -d /dev/loop0`, edit bochs configuration file `image=myfloppy.img` @MichaelPetch . It was this simple, and I wasted my whole day :(

Comment: how to load and call c function in elf file format from my boot loader? if you can help me here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229807/loading-elf-i386-from-my-boot-loader) @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you are are attempting to use `/dev/loop0` in Bochs while it is still open and active as a mount point. It may be possible that after the copy of KRNLDR.SYS to the floppy the file and/or fat tables haven't been flushed from memory to the device.

I really recommend to avoid problems after you modify the bootsector and copy the file:

```
umount myfloppy
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

This should ensure that the disk image is fully updated (synced) and loop device freed up. Then in your Bochs config file you can replace `1_44=/dev/loop0` with `image=myfloppy.img`. Bochs should be able to open the disk image `myfloppy.img` properly.